# List all aliases for a given domain

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, domain-name

For example google.com has the following aliases, gooogle.com, gogle.com (I'm sure it has more than that). Is there a way to list all registered domain aliases for a site/domain name?

Comment: this is _almost_ identical to this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/105061/how-to-find-all-hostnames-in-dns-attached-to-one-ip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they have nothing directly to do with each other other than the same owner.

Answer (score 1):

Chopper3 is absolutely correct, however you can try a "Registrant Search" and maybe see some of them. The problem there is most services will not give you EVERY registered site if a company has registered 1,000,000 sites. It also depends on the name of the person who it is registered under; if they're not all registered under the same "name" (in Google's case the name is the informative "DNS Admin") so that can change.

Answer (score 0):

Some Whois lookup sites offer this information as a premium service, but it by no means is a comprehensive list. I think it is based on collecting Whois and DNS data and then grouping it by IP address. Here is a link to a ["reverse IP lookup"](http://www.domaintools.com/reverse-ip/?hostname=google.com) for the google.com domain, but it will cost you around $15.00 per month to access.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an IP to start with, apparently [Bing can help you.](http://blogs.msdn.com/cdndevs/archive/2009/08/18/finding-domains-on-a-given-ip-address-with-bing.aspx)